# c++ compiler that creates object code for two different machines

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Are there c++ compilers that I can run on a brand x system that will create machine code that will run on a brand y system?  Would this be considered a cross compiler?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that's exactly what a [cross compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) is.

The [GNU Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (which includes gcc and g++) are a prime example of a portable cross compiler with hundreds of supported CPU types.

There are many ways to configure GCC to be a cross compiler. Most of it depends on the target machine and what's available from it - mostly because of the C runtime environment. For example, compiling GCC for an ARM Linux target requires an ARM Linux glibc pre-compiled to build the cross compiler libstdc++.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite common using gcc.

There are a number of tutorials around that describe building your own cross-compiler environment.
[This](http://www.cowlark.com/2009-07-04-building-gcc/) is one, but a quick google will probably provide a link to someone doing exactly the mix of environments that you're after.

edit:
[This](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/current/doc/crosstool-howto.html) is a more thorough tutorial, using crosstool

Comment: There's also this tutorial: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler, which can be used on Windows with Cygwin/MinGW as well as on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is what cross-compilation is about (although I would say "brand X" isn't appropriate classification term).

Comment: Doesn't have to be CPU type - it can be same arch but different runtime. Prime example is Linux x86 cross compiler to Windows x86.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are such compilers; yes, they are called cross compilers.  For example, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) can be configured in this manner, so that I can run the compiler on a 32-bit x86 system, but produce 64-bit code for an x64 system, and that's just the tip of the iceberg.

[Crosstool](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) is a really handy tool suite for creating a cross-compiling GCC.

HTH,

Eric Melski

Electric Cloud, Inc.